# What's causing my pepper plant leaf to curl downwards?

Tags: plant-health, peppers

This is grown indoors.  No insects except fungus gnats.  The plant's color is a healthy green with no spots or yellowing.  The bottom set of leaves were also curling downwards when the plant was about 8 inches tall in the beginning but have flattened out.  I'm guessing it's due to too much water but I'm wondering if it's a viral disease.  The bumps you see are not bug eggs by the way.  It might be edema.

[image]